# CMake Error: variable is NOTFOUND. ACE_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)

Tags: c++, cmake, debian, ace, azerothcore

I just tried to compile the latest AzerothCore on Debian 9 and did not touch the source, just pulled it and used exactly the sh described in the installation guide. CMake gives me that error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
ACE_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
```

Debian 9 with the latest AzerothCore. Ace is definitely installed with their latest version.

Expected: No error.
Actual Result: Error.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get update` then do `sudo apt-get install libace-6.* libace-dev`

current version working for myself at this time is 6.3.3. 
Also, I don't use the sh installer, so not sure if that could be your issue.

I just use `cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/youruser/azeroth-server/ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ -DTOOLS=0 -DSCRIPTS=1`

Answer (score 3):

I started with the TrinityCore requirements and sadly forgot to install the libace needed for AzerothCore. Needed to to `sudo apt-get install libace-6.* libace-dev` like DJ Boxer suggested.